# indexing child document as separated document?

Tags: json, solr, parent-child

When adding child document using  *childDocuments* solr  How do I accept it in indexing as one document bout in query return it as separated document.

```
"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "id":"2",
    "comments":["SolrCloud supports it too!"],
    "_version_":1607834617617842176},
  {
    "id":"1",
    "title":["Solr adds block join support"],
    "content_type":["parentDocument"],
    "_version_":1607834617617842176}]
```

}}

Comment: Do you want to achieve what your example shows? Exactly what are you trying to do, and what have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: i want to get result {Parten{child 1}{child 2}.
 bout i get this result {partnt} {child1} {child2}.
 i'm trying with solr using add child document and also trying with json
using _childDocuments_  key   i get the  same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return children together with your parent, [use the `[child]` document transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_child_-ChildDocTransformerFactory).

> This transformer returns all descendant documents of each parent document matching your query in a flat list nested inside the matching parent document. This is useful when you have indexed nested child documents and want to retrieve the child documents for the relevant parent documents for any type of search query.

```
q=*:*&fl=id,[child parentFilter=content_type:parentDocument]
```